# Show the statuses before a block in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

These 2 are my tables:

```
Issues_storylevel (dimension)
key
key-1
key-2
key-3 ...

History (fact)
key-1   A   01/01/2023
key-1   B   01/01/2023
key-1   Block   03/01/2023
key-1   C   04/01/2023
key-1   Block   06/01/2023
key-2   A   02/01/2023
key-2   B   03/01/2023
key-2   Block   04/01/2023
```

I wanna know the status that the Issue (row-key) was when it has been blocked. The expected result is a table like that:

```
Status  Value
A   1
B   2
```

i have no ideia how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Hi could you rephrase your question as it seems a bit confusing as there is no relation of status A & B to the block count, if you are referring to the number of times the key was blocked then below is the measure assuming Dim_key as the dimension table and Fact_History as the fact table and the relationship between dim and fact table exists.

```
_Count_Block = CALCULATE(COUNT(Fact_History[Status]),Fact_History[Status] = "Block")
```

[image: Dim_Key]

[image: Fact_History]

[image: Result]